# Power BI Linear Regression

Tags: powerbi, linear-regression, dax

I am fairly new to PowerBI/Dax and have been having trouble creating a linear regression. The included trendline feature is not robust enough for my use-case since I need to predict future values and show the equation of best fit. I attempted to modify the code presented in this blog, https://xxlbi.com/blog/simple-linear-regression-in-dax/, but I am unable to graph the measure. It seems to have aggregated all the values together.

One thing to note, in my dataset there are only 11 unique dates. But it is approximately 30k rows to accommodate all the possible filters. I need the linear regression to respond to those possible filters. 
Also, I did create a separate Date table for the present and future values the model should use for calculating.

In another attempt, I modified the default code from the preset Correlation Constant measure to calculate slope and y-intercept.

```
Slope = 
VAR __CORRELATION_TABLE = VALUES('Sheet1'[Date])
VAR __COUNT =
    COUNTX(
        KEEPFILTERS(__CORRELATION_TABLE),
        CALCULATE(COUNTA('Sheet1'[Date]) * SUM('Sheet1'[Expenditure]))
    )
VAR __SUM_X =
    SUMX(
        KEEPFILTERS(__CORRELATION_TABLE),
        CALCULATE(COUNTA('Sheet1'[Date]))
    )
VAR __SUM_Y =
    SUMX(
        KEEPFILTERS(__CORRELATION_TABLE),
        CALCULATE(SUM('Sheet1'[Expenditure]))
    )
VAR __SUM_XY =
    SUMX(
        KEEPFILTERS(__CORRELATION_TABLE),
        CALCULATE(COUNTA('Sheet1'[Date]) * SUM('Sheet1'[Expenditure]))
    )
VAR __SUM_X2 =
    SUMX(
        KEEPFILTERS(__CORRELATION_TABLE),
        CALCULATE(COUNTA('Sheet1'[Date]) ^ 2)
    )
VAR __SUM_Y2 =
    SUMX(
        KEEPFILTERS(__CORRELATION_TABLE),
        CALCULATE(SUM('Sheet1'[Expenditure]) ^ 2)
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE(
        (__COUNT * __SUM_XY - __SUM_X * __SUM_Y),
        (__COUNT * __SUM_X2 - __SUM_X ^ 2)
    )
```

```
Y Intercept = 
VAR __CORRELATION_TABLE = VALUES('Sheet1'[Date])
VAR __COUNT =
    COUNTX(
        KEEPFILTERS(__CORRELATION_TABLE),
        CALCULATE(COUNTA('Sheet1'[Date]) * SUM('Sheet1'[Expenditure]))
    )
VAR __SUM_X =
    SUMX(
        KEEPFILTERS(__CORRELATION_TABLE),
        CALCULATE(COUNTA('Sheet1'[Date]))
    )
VAR __SUM_Y =
    SUMX(
        KEEPFILTERS(__CORRELATION_TABLE),
        CALCULATE(SUM('Sheet1'[Expenditure]))
    )
VAR __SUM_XY =
    SUMX(
        KEEPFILTERS(__CORRELATION_TABLE),
        CALCULATE(COUNTA('Sheet1'[Date]) * SUM('Sheet1'[Expenditure]))
    )
VAR __SUM_X2 =
    SUMX(
        KEEPFILTERS(__CORRELATION_TABLE),
        CALCULATE(COUNTA('Sheet1'[Date]) ^ 2)
    )
VAR __SUM_Y2 =
    SUMX(
        KEEPFILTERS(__CORRELATION_TABLE),
        CALCULATE(SUM('Sheet1'[Expenditure]) ^ 2)
    )
RETURN
    ROUND(DIVIDE(
        (__SUM_Y * __SUM_X2 - __SUM_X * __SUM_XY),
        (__COUNT * __SUM_X2 - __SUM_X ^ 2)),0
    )
```

I originally did this to display the best-fit equation and have been able to successfully 'display' the constants and have them respond to the filters. However, I then tried to use these constants to create the measure for the linear-regression.

```
Linear Regression = 
SUMX (
    DISTINCT('Date'[Date]),
    [Y Intercept] + [Slope] * 'Date'[Date]
)
```

I'm not getting any errors, but I am also not getting any data. The measure shows up as blank. Any insights into what I am doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Why did you have to modify the code from the blog? Blog code is correct; yours is very different from it and has many mistakes.

Comment: When I used the blog code, I only modified where it said to modify. IE I pointed to the columns containing the data I wanted to perform a linear regression on. However, when I attempted to graph that measure only a single value point was represented. A row card showed that value was too large, and not dynamic to filters on the dashboard. My code for calculating a and b is the same as the preset measure for calculating r, except I changed the final calculation.